# Oracle Advanced Queue thread safety in Dequeue

Tags: oracle

I have multi consumer enabled Oracle AQ. I want to dequeue the Q from java in multithread.
My questions : is mulltithread access for dequeue allowed or I have to add some sync block?
Thanks in advance for the help. Please observe the code and provide your valuable comments.

The code snippet is given below.

---

```
private void dequeueTaskInfo(OracleConnection conn, String p_aConsumerName, String p_aQueueName, String p_aPayloadType) throws SQLException 
{
    System.out.println("----------- Dequeue start ------------");

    AQDequeueOptions deqopt = new AQDequeueOptions();
    deqopt.setRetrieveMessageId(true);
    if(p_aConsumerName != null)
    deqopt.setConsumerName(p_aConsumerName);

    deqopt.setWait(2);  

    AQMessage msg = conn.dequeue(p_aQueueName,deqopt,p_aPayloadType);

    if(msg!=null)
    {
     STRUCT struct = msg.getSTRUCTPayload();

     long l_scheduleid = ((struct.getOracleAttributes()))[0].longValue();
     Clob clobMsg = (Clob) ((struct.getOracleAttributes())[1]);
     String l_taskDetails = clobMsg.getSubString(1, (int) clobMsg.length());
     String l_access = ((struct.getOracleAttributes())[2]).stringValue();


     //WRITE CODE TO FORWARD the message

    }
    else
    {
     System.out.println("No data in queue..........");
     conn.close();
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Are you using connection pooling or you want to pass  on connection  to many threads?

Comment: @ Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz, There is a fixed number of threads and each thread will use separate connection

Comment: You don't have to use sync. Multithread access is allowed. AQ persistence queues are normal table in DB. And each operation on queue is transnational. Aq mechanizm dequeue only message in ready state.

Comment: Thanks Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz, but I am using only one Q subscriber and that subscriber name is being used by different threads during dequeue(refer to the parameter p_aConsumerName, this carries the same value for all threads), although the AQ is multiconsumer enables. Will it be OK?

Comment: I will be ok. Both type of queues can be consumed by many thread. Multiconsumer's queue exist for other purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz.